# iOS - Set weekdays for DateComponents

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsdateformatter

I'm just trying to configure a local notification to trigger not only at a time, but also specific days of the week repeatedly for iOS 10, Xcode 8.3.

```
var notificationTimeComponents = DateComponents()
    
    notificationTimeComponents.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    notificationTimeComponents.hour = 10
    notificationTimeComponents.minute = 0
    notificationTimeComponents.weekday = 5
    notificationTimeComponents.weekday = 1 // <--- no good

let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: notificationTimeComponents, repeats: true)
        
let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)
        
center.add(notificationRequest) { (error: Error?) in
    if let theError = error {
        print(theError.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

In the documentation for DateComponents it says:

> var **day**: Int? A day or count of days.
>
> var **weekday**: Int? A weekday or count of weekdays.

It does work with just one weekday component but I'd like many. I'm not sure how to write the 'count of weekdays' in Xcode. Do I have to create a notification for each day separately?

Thank you

Comment: You will need one notification for each day in the week and make it repeat weekly. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42892780/2303865

Comment: BTW count of days just means you can have 100 days. The same for the weekdays

Comment: alright, thanks guys for the help