# How to repeat a UNUserNotification every day?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to allow the user to schedule notifications to open the app at a certain time every day. So far, I've been able to schedule the first notification by calculating the time between now and when the user selects, and scheduling a notification in X seconds. However, is there a way that I can then set that notification to repeat every day? Here's part of my code in case you're confused:

```
let newTime: Double = Double(totalDifference)
let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: newTime, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "openApp", content: notif, trigger: notifTrigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
        completion(false)
    } else {
        completion(true)
    }
})
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: no, I'm not using UILocalNotification

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892780/2303865. You just need to remove the weekday component to make it daily

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, change this line:

```
let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: newTime, repeats: false)
```

to

```
let notifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: newTime, repeats: true)
```

From the Documentation:

**UNCalendarNotificationTrigger**:

> Triggers a notification at the specified date and time. You use a
>   UNCalendarNotificationTrigger object to specify the temporal
>   information for the trigger condition of a notification. Calendar
>   triggers can fire once or they can fire multiple times.

```
NSDateComponents* date = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
date.hour = 8;
date.minute = 30; 
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
                     triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:date repeats:YES];
```

**Swift:**

```
var date = DateComponents()
date.hour = 8
date.minute = 30 
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: date, repeats: true)
```

Comment: the bottom code was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**FOR SWIFT3**

```
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: true)
```