# UNNotificationRequest requires unique identifier, but fires on duplicates too

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios10, ios11

I call local Notifications like so

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = title
content.body = text
content.categoryIdentifier = category
content.userInfo = map
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
content.setValue("YES", forKeyPath: "shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground")
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testing", content: content, trigger: nil)
center.add(request)
```

with the same `UNNotificationRequest` identifier each time (a non-changing string). According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649633-init):

> **identifier**
>
> A unique identifier for the request (if identifier is not unique, a new notification request object is not created). You can use this identifier later to cancel a request that is still pending. This parameter must not be nil.

The local notification fires every time I trigger it, even in the same instance of the app. The identifier is always the same. Are the docs wrong?

Comment: you should never use the same identifier twice.

Comment: I understand that its bad practice, and I don't in production code. But during testing, what I saw contradicted the documentation since they say 'object is not created,' yet a new notification was sent on the same identifier.

Comment: make sure you cancel previous scheduled notifications

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882832/trigger-notification-weekly-swift-3/42892780?s=1|3.1375#42892780

Comment: Not sure how that^ link answers my question regarding why using the same identifier twice still works.

Comment: I just wanted you to read the comment suggesting the use of the trigger date description as your notification identifier

Answer (score 2):

At this point the documentation is corrected and more accurate:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649633-init

> The system uses the identifier parameter to determine how to handle
> the request:
>
> - If you provide a unique identifier, the system creates a new notification.
> - If the identifier matches a previously delivered notification, the system alerts the user again, replaces the old notification with the
>   new one, and places the new notification at the top of the list.
> - If the identifier matches a pending request, the new request replaces the pending request.