# I want to send a notification on specific days of the week

Tags: swift

I just want to send a local notification at 11:55 am Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday. I couldn't find a detailed source. Can you help me?

Comment: do you mean using APNs ?

Comment: @7bebMrto Sorry. I want to send local notifications.

Comment: First of all, please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications.

Regarding local notifications this article should help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Comment: @D.Mika dateComponents.weekday = 3
So how do I do this for more than one day.

Comment: @Umut Can Alparslan: AFAIK you have to create a UNCalendarNotificationTrigger and a UNNotificationRequest for each weekday.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892780/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and create a trigger. You can set date, timezone, year, month, day, hour, minute and if need repeat or not.
Next, create a request `UNNotificationRequest`, and finish adding the request to Notification Center.

Like this:

```
import UserNotifications

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, timeZone: Calendar.current.timeZone, year: 2019, month: 1, day: 14, hour: 11, minute: 55, repeats: true )
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

You can create (schedule) only 64 local notifications